# I just got started in coding, and I'm making a simple 2d platformer. My character sometimes jumps and sometimes not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

This is the code I'm using right now, the character does jump sometimes, but at other times it just stands there not responding to the key I'm pressing.
I'm new at coding so any recommendation will be helpful. Also, english is not my first language so sorry if I have some mistakes or I'm mispelling something

```
public float moveSpeed;
[Range(1,20)]
public float jumpMec;
private bool grounded = false;

void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") < 0.5f) {
        transform.Translate (new Vector2 (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f));
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")) {
        if (grounded) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = Vector2.up * jumpMec;
        }
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D() {
    grounded = true;
}

void OnTriggerExit2D() {
    grounded = false;
}
```

Comment: The obvious answer would be that "grounded" is not set to true/false as you expect it too. Have you verified what the value is when jumping is not working? Something like a else block that enabeles a debug message could help you nail it down.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that sometimes the character collider didn't actually trigger, that's why "Grounded" wasn't actually setting to true/false as I expected

Comment: Careful with such a generic rule for setting "grounded".  Depending on the type of game you are making, you might end up with funny interactions.  Falling but next to a wall?  The trigger will fire and you'll be "grounded" and able to jump.  Brushing against a ceiling with your (presumably large) collider?  Suddenly you'll have jumps again.  Make sure the bounds of your collider are appropriate.  Good job though!

Comment: The idea was to use the trigger mechanics to create some kind of "Walljump" to make the platformer a little different and more entertaining, but I've learnt from my mistake and now I will try and find another way to make that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, take a look at your first `if`, I think it should be `0.5` and `-0.5`... Otherwise it's always true, unless it's exactly 0.5. Which never happens.

Comment: That's true Markus, I've realized that as well but thanks for your help!